# Spoon converting Saturdays from table input to the Fridays into the table output

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation which is having table 1-table input 1-row filter 1- table output. When I am inserting all Saturdays from table input to table output, those Saturdays becoming Fridays( I mean time is decreased by few hours which is making date as friday). can someone tell me the issue.

I thought it is because of daylight saving and AWS Ec2 tuned to that date. if it so, the date should be only differ by only an hour. but it is more than that.

Comment: There probably is some extensive explanation on DATETIME data types someone can give (and should if they don't mind the extensive part), but it would seem your servers have DATETIMEOFFSET, and you're using DATATIME types, i would try to rebuild this date without the time part before insert, or insert this date as String(again without the time part) to the output and use a function to convert the String to Date.

Comment: There can be multiple things like server time and server timezone is different from your input source.